# How to change the text " Material ActionBar"

Tags: android

How to change the text " Material ActionBar"?
I can't find the code to change it..help.

[A Material ActionBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk5JK.png)

Comment: What you tried so far ??

Comment: Is "Material ActionBar" the name of your app?

Comment: I tried to find the code and change it.

Comment: Egor, nop is a activity and the name is Download.

Answer (score 0):

The "Material ActionBar" is called `Toolbar` and you can use these methods to change the titles:

```
setTitle()
setSubTitle()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi in your AndroidManifest.xml inside application tag declare your activity if not declared and inside the declared activity tag you need to set label like below:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".main.MainActivity"
            android:label="Your Custom Name"
         />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Title for your Activity would be the label specified in the **AndroidManifest.xml** as @Surrender Kumar has given as a solution:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity"
    android:label="Name in Toolbar"
 />
```

But if you would want to override it and set it manually, you could do as @MarcGV says and use the methods inside the onCreate() method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    setTitle("Your Desired Title");
    ...
}
```